# Параллельное выполнение циклов в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

В програмке есть два цикла while, как сделать так, чтобы они работали одновременно?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Используйте модуль [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html):

```
from threading import Thread

def f():
    for i in range(3):
        print('Я из функции f и я несу ', i)

def f_2():
    for i in range(3):
        print('Я из функции f_2 и я несу ', i)

th_1, th_2 = Thread(target=f), Thread(target = f_2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    th_1.start(), th_2.start()
    th_1.join(), th_2.join()
```

Результат:

```
Я из функции f и я несу  0
Я из функции f_2 и я несу  0
Я из функции f и я несу  1
Я из функции f_2 и я несу  1
Я из функции f и я несу  2
Я из функции f_2 и я несу  2
```

Comment: 1- `a, b` в Питоне слева направо выполняется (не одновременно), то есть `th_1.start(), th_2.start()` можно было бы на разных строчках с тем же эффектом написать. `a, b` создаёт tuple в Питоне. Вы вероятно хотели `a; b` написать или вообще на отдельных строчках для ясности. 2- Если нагрузить CPU в этих циклах, используя чистый Питон, то мы увидим, что только один CPU загружен на CPython -- выполнение будет чередоваться, но только один поток активно выполняет Питон-код из-за GIL (он отпускается при вызове блокирующих системных функций (к примеру ввода/вывода), в C расширениях таких как numpy)

Comment: @jfs это очевидно :)

Answer (score 4):

```
from asyncio import coroutine, ensure_future, gather, get_event_loop
import time, random

def func1(a):
    while a < 3:
        print('func1', a)
        a += 1
        time.sleep(random.randrange(3))
    return 'func1 = %s' % a

def func2(a):
    while a < 5:
        print('func2', a)
        a += 1
        time.sleep(random.randrange(3))
    return 'func2 = %s' % a

@coroutine
def async_worker(fn, a):
    r = yield from LOOP.run_in_executor(None, fn, a)
    return r

@coroutine
def async_map():
    workers = [ensure_future(async_worker(func1, 0), loop=LOOP),
               ensure_future(async_worker(func2, 0), loop=LOOP)]
    result = yield from gather(*workers, loop=LOOP)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LOOP = get_event_loop()
    result = LOOP.run_until_complete(async_map())
    print(result)
```

out:

```
func1 0
func2 0
func2 1
func1 1
func2 2
func1 2
func2 3
func2 4
['func1 = 3', 'func2 = 5']
```

--

```
def func1():
    a = 0
    while a < 2:
        a += 1
        print('func1', a)
        yield a

def func2():
    b = 0
    while True:
        a = yield
        print('func2', a)
        b += a
        yield b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn2 = func2()
    next(fn2)

    for a in func1():
        b = fn2.send(a)
        print('b = %s' % b)
        next(fn2)
```

out:

```
func1 1
func2 1
b = 1
func1 2
func2 2
b = 3
```

Comment: В вашем коде в `func1` попробовал убрать `sleep` вообще, а в `func2` оставить `sleep(1)`. Все равно результат выдается моментально. Почему так? Вот [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) написано, что по возможности `time.sleep` использует `select`. Может, дело в этом?

Comment: видимо надо сделать больше итераций цикла