# Как запустить два скрипта одновременно?

Tags: python, pyqt5

В одном ру файле у меня лежит интерфейс, в другом сам скрипт. Как сделать так, чтобы интерфейс запускался параллельно со скриптом?

вот код скрипта

```py
import os

import sys

from time import sleep

from config import *

exec(main.py) # Название второго файла

os.system("pip install -r requirements.txt")
```

Comment: Тимофей Шулимов, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Параллельное выполнение циклов в Python 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677465/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-python-3)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakinable мне нужно выполнять два отдельный файла параллельно, я попробовал создать третий, в него импортировал оба файла и треадинг, но всё равно запускается только первый

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+QProcess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from threading import Thread

def run_another(script_name, threaded=False):
    try:
        script_content_io = open(script_name, 'r')
        script_content = script_content_io.read()

        script_content_io.close()

        if threaded:
            threaded = Thread(target=lambda: exec(script_content))
            threaded.start()

        else:
            exec(script_content)
    except Exception as err:
        return err

run_another('НАЗВАНИЕ_СКРИПТА', True) # #1 - Название скрипта, #2 - Запустить в другом потоке.
```

script_name = Название скрипта.
threaded = Запустить скрипт в другом потоке.

Если ошибка, вернет ошибку, если нет, вернет None.

Comment: @https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/427921/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82 cпасибо огромное!!!!!!!